# How can I use COUNTIF, such that it's reliant on a filter, and a pivot table all in one?

Tags: excel, statistics, tableau-api, analysis

So here's my problem.

I'm using the COUNTIF feature to return a count of all the instances of multiple text queries (all the instances of NHL teams) within a certain range (columns H:W). Easy.

From here I'd like to be able to see this COUNTIF table respond to a filter based on my respondents answer to another question (Column E) which, in this case, is what team they selected as their favourite.

So ideally I'd like to look at how many responses of "x team" via COUNTIF, based on answering a different "x team". 
Or in terms of my actual data: see how many times "Anaheim Ducks", "Boston Bruins", all 31 teams etc, are listed in columns H through W (over 2200 rows), after filtering this by respondents who selected "Calgary Flames" as their favourite team.

To me this sounds like using a pivot table? Potentially SUMIF? However, I'm not entirely sure that's what I need nor how to set it up properly.

Here are some screenshots of the data I'm working with:
This is the dataset showing the column I want to sort by, and the columns that I'm using COUNTIF on.

[image]

This is the COUNTIF table that I want to respond to my filter of column E in the previous screenshot.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot or some sample data would go a long way here. It's a bit unclear what you're asking. `COUNTIFS` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I’ll go with @BigBen  here...

Comment: Added some screenshots, hope they help contextualize what I was saying. @BigBen